# Comparing two tables for missing records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to compare two tables for missing records and setting the status to **Yes**, if all records of **Table-B** exists in **TABLE-A** and **NO** when any one of the record is missing ?. Say for example,

**Table A**

8000010001

8000011001

8000025001

8000025002

---

**Table B**

8000010

8000010001

8000010002

8000011

8000011001

8000012

8000012001

8000023

8000023001

8000025

8000025001

8000025002

8000026

8000026001

8000026002

---

**Output**

8000010    NO

8000011    YES

8000012    NO

8000023    NO

8000025    YES

8000026    NO

---

**Note** - Please check **Table B**, you can find parent and child relationship among records. For example 8000010, 8000010 001, 8000010 002. The parent records(8000010, 8000011, 8000012...) does not appear in **Table A**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
declare @tableA table(id varchar(10))
insert into @tableA values('800010001')
insert into @tableA values('8000011001')
insert into @tableA values('8000025001')
insert into @tableA values('8000025002')

declare @tableB table (id varchar(10))
insert into @tableB values('8000010')
insert into @tableB values('8000010001')
insert into @tableB values('8000010002')
insert into @tableB values('8000011')
insert into @tableB values('8000011001')
insert into @tableB values('8000012')
insert into @tableB values('8000012001')
insert into @tableB values('8000023')
insert into @tableB values('8000023001')
insert into @tableB values('8000025')
insert into @tableB values('8000025001')
insert into @tableB values('000025002')
insert into @tableB values('8000026')
insert into @tableB values('8000026001')
insert into @tableB values('8000026002')
```

Using left join you can solve this problem.  But the best way would be mapping of both tables by an unique id.

//Comparing tableA with tableB

```
select a.id, case when b.id IS null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as Status from @tableA a left join @tableB b on a.id = b.id
```

//comparing tableB with tableA

```
select b.id, case when a.id IS null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as Status from @tableB b left join @tableA a on a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

we need to first split the records to make parent child relation ship

The first `CTE` does this split up , it would be good to change your table to be of this format instead of single ID like now.

```
ID          parent
8000010     NULL
8000010001  8000010
8000010002  8000010
```

second `CTE` does `JOIN` with TableA to find the matching records
Finally the actual children count is matched with results from second `CTE` to mark it as NO or YES

```
; WITH cte
as
(
SELECT ID, 
       case when Id/10000000 >0 
             then ID/1000
             else NULL
             end as parent
FROM TableB
)
, cte1
as
(
SELECT cte.parent, count(cte.id) as matchedChildrenCount
FROM cte
JOIN tableA A
ON cte.id = A.id

WHERE cte.parent is not null
GROUP BY parent 
)

SELECT T.parent, CASE WHEN cte1.parent is null or T.childrenCount <> cte1.matchedChildrenCount
                      THEN 'No' else 'Yes' 
                      END as value from 
(select parent, 
        COUNT(cte.id) as childrenCount   
 FROM cte 
 where cte.parent is not null
 group by parent 
 ) T
 left join cte1
 on cte1.parent = T.parent
```